# done loading events callback after calling gotoDate method in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to change the view by calling gotoDate and then apply additional classes using jQuery to selected events after pressing a button.

The problem is that the events are loaded using ajax, so adding classes to the events is 'done' before the events are ready. Is there a way to make sure all the events are loaded before modifying the events?

I think I want to use the loading callback, but I'm not sure how to access it after calling gotoDate after clicking on a button.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/loading/

jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/waspinator/akbyW/110/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        // Multiple Sources
        eventSources: [
        'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.german%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic'
        ],
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $('#loading').show();
            } else {
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        }
    });

    $( "#highlight" ).on( "click", function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', 2014, 4);
        $('.fc-event:nth-child(4)').addClass('highlight');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/waspinator/akbyW/113/

add the events you want to be highlighted to a global array and then using the loading callback call a function that highlights any events in that array. you also want to call that function in the button click event in case the loading callback isn't triggered. (happens when you are already on the view needed). I also added an unhighlight button in case you need to remove the highlights.

```
var highlight_these_events = [];

function highlightSelectedEvents() {

    for (var index = 0; index < highlight_these_events.length; index++) {
        $(highlight_these_events[index]).addClass('highlight');
    } 

}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        // Multiple Sources
        eventSources: [
        'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.german%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic'
        ],
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $('#loading').show();
            } else {
                $('#loading').hide();
                highlightSelectedEvents();
            }
        }
    });

    $( "#highlight" ).on( "click", function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', 2014, 4);        
        highlight_these_events.push('.fc-event:nth-child(4)');
        highlightSelectedEvents();
    });

    $( "#unhighlight" ).on( "click", function() {
        $('.fc-event').removeClass('highlight');
    });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/ which is triggered during render.

Edit:
You should add eventRender to your calendar creation. From the example:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-01',
            description: 'This is a cool event'
        }
        // more events here
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.find('.classToAddTo').addClass('newClass'); // Here is where you will use jquery to add your new class/classes
    }
    });
```

Comment: so what would be the best way of receiving that call back after pressing a button? Or should I call a function 'modifyEvents()' every time in the eventRender callback that reads a global array variable of events to modify which is assigned during the button press?

Comment: eventRender is called by fullcalendar when processing events. If you wish you can add your own function modifyEvents() in the eventRender you can do that also vs adding your logic straight in eventRender. What is it that you are trying to accomplish? You said you are trying to add classes?

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough in my question, or I may be misunderstanding your answer. I want to add a class after clicking a button. The button first calls $('#calendar').fullcalendar('goToDate', year, month) and then I add a class to certain events based on their 'rel' attribute. It works fine, as long as the goToDate doesn't change the view.

Comment: What view are you in? Are you looking to update existing events? Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I added an example to my question. if you click on the highlight button while on in May, "May Day" will become highlighted. If instead you first go to June, and then click on the button it will go to may but "May Day" will not be highlighted.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want "May Day" to be highlighted in either case: Being in May before pressing the button, or being in any other month and pressing the button.